# Kill process in Java

Tags: java, java.lang.class

I run process from my Java code like this `p = run.exec("cmd /c start \"\" C:\\<nameof .cmd file>");`. At some point, I want to kill this process. Calling `destroy()` method on process kill the process, but I want to turn off command line, where procces is still running. When I looked to Task Manager, this process has no name, it has only postfix `.exe`.

In Task Manager, it look like this:
[image]

So I cannot do this `p = run.exec("taskkill /F /IM <nameofexe>.exe");`, because this running process dont have name.

Is there a way, how to completely turn off cmd and kill this running process?

Answer (score 0):

When you launched your process, the CMD call may have launched additional child processes.  Odds are good your second command line is killing one of the children, but not the CMD itself.  The ideal situation would be to kill the launched process, not to run a second command line executable to kill (possibly) one of the children.

```
Process child = run.exec("cmd /c start \"\" C:\\<nameof .cmd file>");
if (timeToKillTheProcess) {
    child.destroy();
    child.waitFor();
}
```

Comment: The process, which I am running is a Java project. How can I please capture PID upon launch ?

Comment: `Process child = run.exec("cmd /c start \"\" C:\"` makes call to cmd. I clearly dont understand first part of your message.

Comment: @M.Barabas Ok this third edit cuts out the extra info, and hopefully is very clear.  The PID is stored inside the `Process` object, but you don't need it if  you use the object's built-in `destroy()` function.  The `Process` object will do the correct `taskkill` for you.

Comment: When I call `detroy()` immediately after after `run.exec`, the process is killed immediately and it not run :(

Comment: @M.Barabas I was answering the question of how to destroy it. You will have to put some logic around that to destroy it at the point in time when you want to destroy it.

Comment: So, I need to run second command executable. That why this solution will not work for me.

Comment: @M.Barabas No, you don't need to run a second command executable to kill the first one you launched.  Java is not a replacement for `cmd.exe` and for windows shell / batch file scripting.  You just need to detect the condition you are waiting for, and then kill it as appropriate.  I can't figure out when you want to kill it, that depends on why you're killing it.